# How to store a output video from opencv into the dcc.store component of Dash (Plotly)

Tags: python, opencv, plotly, plotly-dash

I have a Dash web-app where the user can select from a dropdown of video names, a CV model will run on the selected video by user and the output video will be displayed. But I don't want the output video to be saved on a local directory each time and rather have it client-side stored into the `dcc.Store` component of Dash.

If this is possible, any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Your question seems paradoxical since a local directory (as seen from the Python code) is server side, while a dcc.Store object is clientside. Could you clarify where you intend to store the data?

Comment: Yeah sorry I messed up with both the terms, thanks for pointing it out. I'll correct my original question.